# AWS Cloudformation provisioning EC2s with FIPS-140 working but Secretsmanager is not

Tags: aws

I have been working on updating our CF Stack across multiple applications to be FIPS-140 enabled; which is working fine for enabling FIPS on the AMI bake jobs. However, once the application is deployed from the pipeline it is failing to work with secretsmanager, any ideas?

Using this guide for fips: https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/fips/

```
 Policies:
        - PolicyName: ApiAccessForAssetInstances
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'cloudwatch:PutMetricData'
                  - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
                  - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
                  - 'secretsmanager:GetSecretValue'
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:AbortMultipartUpload'
                  - 's3:DeleteObject*'
                  - 's3:PutObject*'
                  - 's3:RestoreObject'
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${AssetGroup}-services-product-newlexis-${EnvType}-us-east-1/*"
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${AssetGroup}-services-product-newlexis-${EnvType}-us-east-1"
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::services-configs.${EnvType}"
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::services-configs.${EnvType}/*"
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  *What* exactly are you doing with Secrets Manager, and how does the result you get not match the result you expect?

Comment: @SottoVoce Just updated with the CF template code. Essentially it is a Java application that gets secret value from secretsmanager

Comment: Looks good, but I still can't see the result you expected vs. the result you got.  Is that lone Secrets Manager permission all the process needs?  It doesn't need `ListSecrets` as well?  (some libraries like to list before getting)

Comment: @SottoVoce can we connect somewhere else so I can send you all the  code?